# Should I allow a Sorcerer to learn illusory dragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

Asking for a sorcerer. God knows where, but they heard the spell "Illusory Dragon" and wanted in. I was wondering if - depending on the kind of character their sorcerer is - it would be okay to let them learn it. I mean, it could just be an appropriate expression of their power, right?

Comment: We can't tell you what you should do. If you can tell us what criteria you're interested in (rules legality, balance, etc.) we can help you evaluate them, but we simply do not, and *cannot*, know enough about your specific situation to tell you what you "should" do.

Comment: A possible way to rephrase your question so it is more answerable on this site would be to ask whether allowing this would be *balanced*

Comment: For reference, illusory dragon appears in _Xanathar's Guide to Everything_. It's normally a spell available to wizards, but not sorcerers, whose spell lists are usually more limited, probably to limit overall versatility.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Medix2 says, we could probably answer whether allowing such a thing would be balanced, or result in any unintended rules interactions or whatever, but without a specified goal you're trying to accomplish, we can't really tell you whether you "should" do something because it's entirely opinion-based. If you edit your question to clarify, we might be able to reopen and answer it.