# Would it be balanced to give a Sorcerer access to the Illusory Dragon spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, sorcerer

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 157) features the spell [Illusory Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/illusory-dragon). Maybe it's me, but doesn't the spell description scream Sorcerer (especially Draconic Bloodline)? Imagine my surprise when I saw that the spell is only available to Wizards.

**Would it be balanced to allow this spell for Sorcerers?**

Maybe I am missing some extreme synergy with a Sorcerer class feature that would make it overpowered...

Comment: Interestingly, a similar question was asked before but was opinion based due to its wording: "[Should I allow a Sorcerer to learn illusory dragon? \[closed\]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160496)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It's fine

It's a really high level spell, and I doubt it's on very many Wizards' short-list of spells they would choose on level-up.  It screams Illusionist to me, but I could certainly see a Draconic Bloodline sorcerer having it, even if just for flavor.  It doesn't seem unbalanced at all with other Sorcerer Level 8 spells, and you will have to take it instead of a different spell that you'd take/swap between levels 15 and 20.

To add to this, even the DMG (p. 287) says [changing spell lists](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#ChangingSpellLists) isn't generally a problem, except for the Warlock spell list due to short rest recovery:

> Modifying a class’s spell list usually has little effect on a character’s power but can change the flavor of a class significantly.

Which I suspect is exactly what you want.  **No problem at all.**